# Fetching user info from many databases at one go

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

I have a requirement to fetch all the schema available in 100+ Oracle instances running in RHEL environment.

All the schema information such as username, roles assigned and is to be dumped in one place from where it will be used for other purposes.

Is it feasible? I can provide more info if this question is sounding vague.

Are there any utilities to perform this?

Comment: Very easy to script if you can use a file with SID,username,password lines in

Comment: are these instances running on the same server?

Comment: Different servers - different 100 servers

Comment: @tesla747 then you can use the remote shell to jump between servers, and then between instances to run a single query on many instances to gather information that you need. Or you could use dblink.

Comment: Is it possible through oracle em?

Answer (score 0):

As already said, this is really easy to script e.g using sqlplus + shell scripts.

Since you mentioned Enterprise Manager. Yes, it is possible through EM, but you need to set the preferred credentials for the databases and hosts. Once you have done that, you can execute an SQL on databases, or a group of databases. For example, I created a group called `sandbox_databases` in EM, added 3 databases in this group, then ran the same query for all of them:

```
$ emcli login -username=sysman
$ emcli execute_sql -sql="select count(*) from dba_users" -targets="sandbox_databases:group"
```

And the output is:

```
*******************************************************************************
* Target: XXXXX1:oracle_database
* Execution Status: Succeeded
*******************************************************************************

  COUNT(*)
----------
         9


*******************************************************************************
* Target: XXXXX2:oracle_database
* Execution Status: Succeeded
*******************************************************************************

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12


*******************************************************************************
* Target: XXXXX3:oracle_database
* Execution Status: Succeeded
*******************************************************************************

  COUNT(*)
----------
        10


*******************************************************************************
* Execution Summary
*     Targets Succeeded: 3
*         XXXXX1:oracle_database,XXXXX2:oracle_database,XXXXX3:oracle_database
*     Targets Failed: 0
*******************************************************************************
```